# how to get the index on numbers generated by int arc4random()

Tags: objective-c

How do you get the index of the number appearing from the arc4rand method?. If 4,1,2,3 appear how do you index them . Example 4 would be 0 in the array.

```
int rand=((arc4random()%4)+1);
```

Comment: Could you be please more specific?

Comment: How do you access the numbers in the order in which they appear like if the first number is 4 that is indexed as one in an array

Comment: About which array you are talking?

Comment: a custom array so you put all the numbers generated by the arc4 method into an array. Im sorry for the poorly worded question I just dont know how to word it better.

Comment: Have u ever use NSArray?

Comment: No I havent how would you put arc4ranom numbers into an array?

Comment: Than first go and learn that. Stack overflow is not to learn basic or not to get readymade code. Ask when you implement something and face some problem. Go Here to learn NSArray : http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsarray.html

Answer (score 1):

For getting random number, i did like this:

Suppose, i have a mutable array

```
 NSMutableArray * myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and i kept 5 data in this myArray.
Now I have to generate random number index from myArray.

```
 int randomIndex = (arc4random() % ([myArray count]));
```

Here `randomIndex` is random index of array

Comment: I dont think he want to search random index in array.

Comment: randomIndex is random index in array

Answer (score 0):

try this one. you need to put all that values into array.

```
NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

[array insertObject:@"4" atIndex:0]; 
[array insertObject:@"1" atIndex:1];
[array insertObject:@"2" atIndex:2];
[array insertObject:@"3" atIndex:3];
```

Comment: But how would you put the numbers generated by arc4rand into an array

Comment: cant change int to Id it says

Comment: [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rnd]];  //Here rnd is random number

Answer (score 0):

using array to get index in ios to add all values in array like this

```
//convert int to nsstring and add array
NSArray *array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSStringFromInt(4),NSStringFromInt(1),NSStringFromInt(2),NSStringFromInt(3), nil];

//reverse process to get int value

int value=[[array objectAtIndex:index]integerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing, you might look for this...

```
NSMutableArray *_array = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    [_array addObject:@((arc4random()%4)+1)];
}
```

Comment: NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            [array addObject:@(rand())];
         
        }
        int rand=((arc4random()%4)+1);

Comment: would you use something like that